# What's the equivalent resistance of this circuit?

Tags: resistors, resistance, schematics, parallel, series

I am a student in 10th grade and our teacher gave us this schematic to work with (Remade with circuit lab):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuwgN3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

He asked us to find the equivalent resistance of the circuit. Based on my calculations, 24 Ohms should be the right answer. Apparently my teacher disagreed and told us it was around 2.5 Ohms or so.

I don't know which answer is the correct one, but I am fairly convinced that mine is the most correct one. Since even if my calculations of the series-parallel resistors are wrong, the minimum resistance is going to be 20 Ohms (R1 + R7).

Comment: When asking for eq. resistance one should tell between which points. Assuming as seen by power supply, it is definitely can't be less than 20 Ohm as there are two 10 Ohm resistors in series. I would say you might have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Ask your teacher, "Pretend that R6 is zero ohms. What is the equivalent resistance?" If he answers anything other than 20 ohms, you know you've got a problem.

Comment: I get about 2.6 Ohms looking from the right into the cirtuit, shorting the supply.

Comment: @Samuel, no, if ideal VOLTAGE source, impedance is usually 0.

Comment: Assuming what one would normally calculate in a circuit like this (as in looking into the resistor network from the POV of the voltage source)

R2 + R3 is 20 ohms.
In parallel with R4 (10 ohms) it's 6.67 ohms
In series with R5 (10 ohms) it's 16.67 ohms
In parallel with R6 (10 ohms) it's 6.25 ohms
In series with R1 (10 ohms) and R7 (10 ohms) it's **26.25 ohms**

Comment: Equivalent resistance seen by the source? Or between some other two nodes? If it's what's seen by the source, you know it can't be less than 20, because you have R1, R7, and "the rest of the network" in series.

Comment: Here's your schematic with drawn colored lassos around the incremental steps to take: [Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nERph.png). This is about the same thing as @mike65535 wrote. Perform the green lasso first, then the light blue, then the dark blue, then the purple. By this time the rest should be simple to perform.

Comment: A lesson I learnt from school days: Never blindly trust any teacher

Answer (score -1):

The answer is 26.25 ohms. Verified with a spice modelling program.

Comment: We don't give the answer homework questions on EE.SE. Instead give pointers to allow the question asker to figure it out for themselves.